# How to install the latest version of BigBlueButton (2.5)?

Tags: bigbluebutton

I'm trying to figure out how to install bigbluebutton in a private network.

Is it possible to install bigbluebutton 2.5 using openssl instead of letsencrypt certbot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check the help message of bbb install scripts, there is an option "-d":
  `-d   Skip SSL certificates request (use provided certificates from mounted volume) in /local/certs/`

In my case, I use mkcert to generate the certificate and private key files, then put them under /local/certs:

```
/local/
└── certs
    ├── fullchain.pem
    └── privkey.pem
```

And install the bbb with this command:
`sudo ./bbb-install-2.5.sh -v focal-250 -s 192.168.56.101 -d -g -a -w`

PS:
If you use self signed certificate, don't forget to install the root CAs for     the instances of nodejs and greenlight.